# phpmailer says invalid email when parameter passing

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";

    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username   = "myemail";
    $mail->Password   = "myemailpassword";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAddress("myemail", "name");
        $mail->SetFrom($from);
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $content = $message;

        $mail->MsgHTML($content);
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Error while sending Email.";
            var_dump($mail);
        } 
        else {
            echo "Email sent successfully";
    }
}
?>
```

the code works if I enter the details myself rather than getting them from my html form. for example for $mail->SetFrom("myemail", "my name")

tried defining the variable when I call it in the mail function that didn't work either

Comment: Can you put your HTML form? There is probably an error in the HTML form.

Comment: Note: This form handler will allow anyone to send any email to anyone else with full control over the subject and content. _When_ the bots find it, they will use it to send boatloads of spam. Best practice is to allow only the barest of bare minimum control, eg: the `To:` address and a _piece_ of the body, eg: inserting the sender's name into a template after rigorously enforcing content restrictions.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you're getting?

Comment: What @Sammitch said, except don't even allow them to set the To address. If you need multiple options, offer only those (e.g. sales, support), and validate before using them. Best advice is to start again using [the contact form example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps), which doesn't suffer these problems and has more error checking.